# Ubuntu Blackscreen Post-Installation (nomodeset won't work)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 14.04, system-installation

Trying to install ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, on my second ssd.

In order to load the installer I have to run it with "nomodeset" in order to see it, but it seems to install everything properly.

I restart the computer after the installation is successful and when its time to run ubuntu for the first time I get the blackscreen with white dash instead of the login screen (I get to hear the ubuntu loading sound though).

Here's what I've tried so far (and hasn't worked):

- Loading with nomodeset
- Loading with nomodeset xforcevesa
- Re-downloading ubuntu 14.04
- Updating the grub (it now detects the windows installation on my other ssd so that's good atleast..)
- Loading with recovery mode and doing updates/upgrades/installing drivers
- Trying with ubuntu 10.04.4 which works wonderfully on my laptop (same, installs well but can't get into the login screen afterwards)

.

What more can I try?

Speccs:

CPU: intel core i5-4670K

MB: Gigabyte GA-Z87X-D3H

RAM: (1x 8GB) DDR3 Vengeance

SSD: Samsung 840 EVO 120g

GPU: Asus GeForce GTX 780

To be clear:

ssd 1: Windows with windows loader

hd  2: ...

ssd 3: Where I want Ubuntu to run (Device for boot ubuntu loader installation) <- set as maximum priority on boot

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you answered your own question. Best advice I can give you is to purchase Linux compatible hardware, in your case, a new video card.

Comment: yea I guess but that's not an option though, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me it Worked by doing

```
sudo uninstall flgrx*
```

then i did

```
sudo install flgrx-updates
```

then

```
rebooted
```

For me it was a problem after I added my AMD Radeon Graphic card. The problem I think is when I do updates that cause problems with the AMD driver I downloaded. I think that you shouldn't update your ubuntu often if you're going to play on it. You should wait for any new driver to come out then uninstall the old one upgrade ubuntu install the new one. Or like a friend of mine was saying you could update but exclude your graphic card drivers from the update.